# Can we write JsonPath expression to remove a node from the jsonObject?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I mean in the example specified here https://jsonpath.com/ if i want to delete `phoneNumbers` node,   can we do that?

I want to do similar thing for an OutputPath in AWS state machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON Path to identify the node that needs to be removed, but you need something else to do the removal.

JSON Path is only for querying.  It doesn't support data transformations.